# Класс однонаправленное кольцо - C++

Tags: c++, классы

Разработать класс реализующий список (однонаправленное кольцо). **Элемент списка содержит информацию о товаре на складе фирмы. Элемент очереди содержит наименование товара, цену, количество и дату поставки.**

Вот реализация класса. Как видно я использую в структуре одно поле. Я не могу понять задание, элемент списка это данные в структуре? А элемент очереди это где данные должны быть?

**my_list.h**

```
    struct nodes {
    char data[256]; //Информация о товаре
    nodes* next;
};


class my_list {
public:
    void insert(char* str); //Вставляет запись за текущей.
    void insert(nodes* nod); //Вставляет запись за текущей(перегрузка)
    void del_next();        //Удаляет запись за текущей.
    void go_next();         //Переходит к следующей записи.
    void go_first();        //Переходит к первой записи.
    const char* show();     //возвращает указатель на хранимые данные.
    int  size();            //Возвращает количество элементов в списке.

    my_list();
    ~my_list();
private:
    nodes *head;           //начало списка.
    nodes *position;       //активная (текущая) запись.
    int     count;          //количество элементов списка.

    void free();            //удаляет все элементы, освобождает память
};
```

и описание методов **my_list.cpp**

```
    my_list::my_list() {
    head = NULL;
    count = 0;
    go_first();
}

my_list::~my_list() {
    free();
}

//public:

void my_list::insert(char* str) {
    //Вставляет запись за текущей.
    nodes* new_node = new nodes;
    strcpy_s(new_node->data, str);
    if (position != NULL) {
        new_node->next = position->next;
        position->next = new_node;
    }
    else {
        new_node->next = new_node;
        position = head = new_node;
    }
    count++;
}


void my_list::insert(nodes* new_node) {
    //Вставляет запись за текущей.

    if (position != NULL) {
        new_node->next = position->next;
        position->next = new_node;
    }
    else {
        new_node->next = new_node;
        position = head = new_node;
    }
    count++;
}

void my_list::del_next() {
    //Удаляет запись за текущей.
    if (position != NULL) {
        nodes* tmp = position->next;
        position->next = position->next->next;

        if (tmp == head) head = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    count--;
}

void my_list::go_next() {
    //Переходит к следующей записи.
    if (position != NULL)
        position = position->next;
}

void my_list::go_first() {
    //Переходит к первой записи.
    position = head;
}

const char* my_list::show() {
    //возвращает указатель на хранимые данные.
    if (position != NULL)
        return position->data;
    else
        return NULL;
}

int my_list::size() {
    //Возвращает количество элементов в списке.
    return count;
}

// private:

void my_list::free() {
    //удаляет все элементы, освобождает память
    go_first();
    while (head->next != head) del_next();
    del_next();
}
```

Comment: Реализация `del_next` не будет работать правильно при удалении самого последнего элемента кольца. Кольцо должно стать пустым, т.е. `position` и `head` должны стать null, но этого не делается. Вместо этого они станут "подвешенными" указателями. Также реализация `del_next` почему-то делает `count--` безусловно, даже если список был изначально пуст (???).

Comment: Также непонятно, зачем писалась функция `insert(nodes* new_node)`, если даже `insert(char* str)` не хочет ее использовать :) Ну и, конечно, самая идея хранить в списке некий "текущий"  элемент (`position`) порочна чуть менее чем полностью. Встречается в студенческом коде относительно часто - не ясно, откуда пошла эта манера.

Comment: @AnT, уже убрал insert(char*), насчет del_next вы правы. Сейчас разбираюсь с этим

Comment: Я бы сказал, что в рамках выбранного подхода именно `insert(char*)` надо было бы оставить, а убрать `insert(nodes* new_node)`. Или (лучше), оставить обе функции, `insert(nodes* new_node)` сделать `private` и в реализации `insert(char*)` *вызывать* `insert(nodes* new_node)` (а не переписывать содержимое внутрь, как сейчас).

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии, всё исправил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо внимательнее читать задание!

В структуре должны быть "предметные" поля:

- наименование товара
- цена
- количество
- дата поставки

И одно "служебное" - указатель на очередной элемент типа структуры, собственно, с помощью которого и реализуется список.

Примерно вот так:

```
struct Node {
  std::string Name;
  double Cost;
  size_t Amount;
  std::time_t DateTime;
  Node *Next; 
};
```

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, просто добавить эти поля в структуру. И условие будет выполнено?

Comment: Да. Четыре поля для данных, и одно поле - указатель на "следующий" элемент списка. Раз требуется кольцевой список, значит в последнем элементе указатель должен указывать на адрес первого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо вы меня выручили. Как смогу засчитать ответ, сразу поставлю)

Comment: Незачто. Еще маленькое дополнение ... Коль вы реализуете методы работы с товаром - имеет смысл не выносить данные в отдельную структуру, а реализовать это в самом классе (вместе с методами).

Comment: Вы меня привели в тупик, я не очень понимаю как использовать в классе

Comment: Класс или струкрура - не суть, в них можно объявлять методы, которые работают со "своими" данными. Разница только в том, что класс по умолчанию свои методы и данные "скрывает" (нужно их явно объявлять публичными, если это требуется), а структура по умолчанию открыта.